# methods of face detection?

Tags: opencv, face-detection, emotion

i want to know the best method of face detection because i'm working on  predict face emotion application

so Before analyzing the facial expression of a face fixed or moving, it should detect or follow to extract relevant information. several
detection methods existe but what is the best in my case ?

Comment: Even if you will create a mechanism that detects facial expression, it's impossible to determine which emotion (and also it's strength) was expressed because of individual differences. Every people use different mentality paradigms and before you will try to recognize any emotion on face you should learn how this man usually express it. It's biological fact.

Comment: @JohnJohansen human emotion recognition is an open research topic, and much like all open research topics, it's not particularly reliable yet. However calling it impossible is a bit premature, although judging human emotion just based on the face and ignoring other modalities (e.g. vocal or physiological) won't be very accurate at this point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fast and easy way to get started with face detection is through using OpenCV's Haar detection methods (a slightly modified version of the viola-jones face detection algorithm IIRC). They have pre-trained haar cascade classifiers for entire faces and individual face components, e.g. eyes, nose, etc. You can also train your own if you feel so inclined. Haar features also have the advantage of being very fast, so it's quite usable with video (which it sounds like you'll be using). Also, by having the individual face-components classified, it may simplify your emotion detection/prediction algorithm.

You can find the OpenCV documentation detailing Haar feature-based object recognition at http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#viola01

and an example of performing face detection at http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/master/entry/samples/cpp/dbt_face_detection.cpp

As for the emotion detection, that's an open research question, so anything you try will likely be fairly involved. If you're into that sort of thing, some good papers to look over  might be http://www.utdallas.edu/dept/eecs/research/researchlabs/msp-lab/publications/Busso_2004.pdf and http://humansensing.cs.cmu.edu/papers/Automated.pdf

Comment: Thank you for these information - I read it few days ago and it helped me a lot.